# Set toggle on an image

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Have altered the code below for toggle on @item["name"]. But dropdown now displays for all items (5 entries) instead of one at a time.

How can I change this.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".name").click(function () {
            $(".dropdown").fadeToggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>



<table class="diag" style="background: url('.png');border:none">
                <tbody>


                    @foreach (var item in Model.project)
                    {                            
                            @:<tr>

                            <td class="image">
                            <img src="@item["image"]" />

                        </td>
                        <td class="name">@item["name"]</td>
<td class="dropdown">
    <ul>
        <li>Option 1</li>
        <li>Option 2</li>
        <li>Option 3</li>
        <li>Option 4</li>
        <li>Option 5</li>
    </ul>
</td>

                        @:</tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Where is your dropdown?

Comment: what about `$('image').click(function() { ... });`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not provide enough information, The best selector at this moment is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td.image img").click(function(){
        $("p").toggle();
    });
});
```

---

EDIT: Based on your added HTML, you need to use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td.image img").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.image').siblings('.dropdown').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, but when the page opens all drop boxes are open.

Comment: How can I close the last dropdown when another image is selected. At the moment all dropdowns stay open unless the same image is clicked again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img").click(function(){
    $("p").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

Of course, if you have multiple images and paragraphs, the selectors need to be more specific. But your code doesn't show the paragraph so I can't create an example for that.